# Forcing default values for method

Tags: ruby

Given the method:

```
def foo(a,b=5,c=1)
    return a+(b*c)
end
```

Running `foo(1)` should return `6`. However, how would you go about doing something like this: `foo(1,DEFAULT,2)`. I need to change the third value, but use the default second value.

How would you do this? (Note: I can't just change the order of the variables because they are arguments for a method from a gem)

Comment: That cannot be done. Use named parameters. `foo(1) #=> 5`.

Comment: Er, yes, #=> 6` (thought it was `a*(b*c)`.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by not being able to change the order of the variables.

Comment: @CarySwoveland it is a method from a gem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it, in the terms posed. This sort of situation is exactly why named (keyword) parameters were introduced in Ruby 2. But *your* parameters with default values, according to the terms of the question, are *not* named.

Therefore, they are *positional* — that is why the optional parameters must come last — and the rule is, accordingly, that this method must be called with at least one argument (because `a` is not optional), and any further arguments will be used *in the order supplied* to fill in the corresponding parameters.

Thus, you can supply `a`, or `a` and `b`, or `a` and `b` and `c`. You cannot supply `a` and `c` alone, as you could easily do if these parameters were named.

Two obvious solutions spring to mind.

- Call the method, supplying the default value of the second parameter as the second argument. Presumably you know what it is, so it's not much of a hardship:

  ```
  foo(1,5,2)
  ```
- Write a trampoline method that does the same thing, but where the parameters *are* named:

  ```
  def foo(a,b=5,c=1)
    return a+(b*c)
  end
  def bar(a,b:5,c:1)
    return foo(a,b,c)
  end
  bar(1,c:2) # => 11
  ```

Comment: It's a clever trick, but if the default of `foo` changes this wrapper method must change as well.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to default to `nil` and then default in the body of the code:

```
def foo(a,b=nil,c=nil)
  b ||= 5
  c ||= 1

  a + (b * c)
end
```

Or you can do that as part of the computation:

```
def foo(a,b=nil,c=nil)
  a + (b || 5) * (c || 1)
end
```

Comment: But I think the implication is that the definition of `foo` is not up to him.

Comment: @Punknoodles You're kind of stuck. There's no way of knowing what a default value is in a general way. I'd manually supply whatever default value it's expecting.

Comment: @tadman yeah, I just realized that the values I was using is deprecated. They use an options hash now. It works a lot better this way.

Comment: @Punknoodles I think you've discovered why they switched. That approach of using hash options makes way more sense if you need to skip args.

Comment: I wonder why they didn't just change to named parameters, unless it had to do with compatibility for older versions of Ruby.

Comment: @CarySwoveland A lot of older libraries (e.g. Rails) used conventional hashes, not necessarily keyword arguments even though the two things work largely the same in practice. It's a stylistic approach more than a technical one. Often you find that your optional parameters are really pick and choose, not necessarily in-order like you initially thought, when you really use your code.